# How to disable extends/precedes charaters in nowrap

Tags: wrapping, options

I want to view a big blob of text (ascii-graphics), but when I use `:set nowrap` some `<` and `>` symbols appears at the left and right borders of the buffer window.

They are kinda annoying and I want to use maximum of available width.

How can hide them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command

```
:set listchars-=extends:>,precedes:<
```

will "hide" them by removing them from the 'listchars' list. You can also change their value by modifying the string after the colon(:). (Colon and comma are forbidden.)

The way `:set-=` works you need to pass the exact values to remove them, so it might be a good idea to check the values with

```
:set listchars?
```

before you remove them.